# Ошибка: RuntimeWarning

Tags: python

При работе с двумя двумерными массивами у меня в какой-то момент выдаётся ошибка:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Соотвественно рисовать он тоже ничего не хочет скорее всего из-за за вышеназванной проблемы. Я подозреваю, что это связано с тем, что у меня в какой -то момент программа делит число на очень маленькое и получает очень большое, которое не влезает в 4 байта или 8 (уже сам не помню). Как быть с такой проблемой? Есть ли способы обойти очень большие числа? Или может существуют библиотеки специальные для работы с ними. Зараннее благодарен за помощь

P.S. Код я проверял, и там все должно быть правильно с точки зрения синтаксиса и разностной схемы. Код пишу на Python

Comment: Возможно вам поможет это: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/

Comment: 1. Зачем вы удалили traceback из тела ошибки ? 2. Приведите минимальный пример демонстрирующий воспроизведение ошибки.

Comment: Если вы используете numpy попробуйте на массив применить метод numpy.ma.fixed_invalid